# split dataframe twice and merge based on columns

Tags: r, merge, split, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a sampleID, chromosome, start and stop, and mean score. I wish to combine each the mean score for each sampleID in each chrom with all possible combinations of start.pos and end.pos in all the sampleIDs. So to merge all the possible start.pos and end.pos for each chromosome, and add the $mean score for each combination for all the sampleIDs.

input:

```
      sampleID     chrom start.pos  end.pos  meancol
1.1   0012102_A01     1         0  11194349    1
1.4   0012102_A01     1  11194349  11492125    0
1.5   0012102_A01     1  11492125  71442329    1
1.9   0012102_A01     1  71442329 249250621    1
1.13  0012102_A02     1         0  65493011    1
1.92  0012102_A02     1  65493011  66164733    1
1.102 0012102_A02     1  66164733 121347754    1
1.52  0012102_A02     1 121347754 249250621    0
1.14  0012102_A03     1         0  56384956    1
1.83  0012102_A03     1  56384956 106266297    1
1.73  0012102_A03     1 106266297 249250621    0
1.15  0012102_A04     1         0  51484139    1
1.27  0012102_A04     1  51484139 249250621    0
2.1   0012102_A01     2         0  50000001    1
2.2   0012102_A01     2  50000001 250000001    1
2.3   0012102_A02     2         0  50000001    0
2.7   0012102_A02     2  50000020 270000001    0
2.18  0012102_A03     2         0  50000004    0
2.19  0012102_A03     2  50000004 250000001    0
1.15  0012102_A04     2         0  51484139    0
1.27  0012102_A04     2  51484139 249250621    0
```

output: here all the mean scores from each sampleID has been added for all possible start.pos and end.pos combinations for each chromosome.

```
chrom start.pos   end.pos meancol
1          0  11194349    4
1   11194349  11492125    3
1   11492125  51484139    4
1   51484139  56384956    3
1   56384956  65493011    3
1   65493011  66164733    1
1   66164733  71442329    3
1   71442329 106266297    2
1  106266297 121347754    1
1  121347754 249250621    1
2          0  50000001    1
2   50000001  50000004    0
2   50000004  50000020    0
2   50000004  51484139    0
2   51484139 249250621    0
2  249250621 250000001    0
```

Comment: Is your input related to your output somehow?

Comment: I think you need to further explain how you get your output `mean` and how you choose your output `stat.pos` and `end.pos` to get some better answers.

Comment: I have edited it, hopefully with a better explanation. I am essentially collapsing the dataframe, for the first row from          start - 0  and stop - 11194349 the input shows 1, in the output it shows 4 for this region because there are 4 samples with a score of 1.

Answer (score 1):

Use data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydataframe)[order(start.pos,end.pos),list(summean=sum(meancol)),by=list(sampleID, chrom)]
```

You should not name a column as 'mean' as mean is a function and there can be confusion.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that easily with `dplyr` package

```
output <- input_data %>%
           group_by(sample_ID,chrom) %>%
           order(start.pos,end.pos) %>%
           summarize(Mean = mean(mean))
```

If this doesn't help you try to provide a reproducible example.